# Need to update the unpaid_bal in the savings table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my  savings table:

```
Accountnumber    yearquarter     savingstype    unpaid_bal    statustype
101               20041             umkc           200           p
101               20041             umkc          -100           w
101               20041             umkc          -100           w
102               20072             ucm            50            a
102               20072             ucm           -50            w
103               20081             ku             200           p
```

Here in this savings table whenever there is statustype type called 'w' within that Accountnumber,yearquarter,savingstype and if the sum(unpaid_bal)=0 
within that Accountnumber,yearquarter,savingstype we need to update the each and every  unpaid_bal in savingstype for all statustype's as "ZERO"

consider the account number 101,102 : In that savingstype umkc it has a status called 'w' and sum of unpaid _bal is "zero" so we need to make un paid bal ashown below:

```
Accountnumber    yearquarter     savingstype    unpaid_bal    statustype
101               20041             umkc           0           p
101               20041             umkc           0           w
101               20041             umkc           0           w
102               20072             ucm            0           a
102               20072             ucm            0           w
103               20081             ku             200         p
```

Here 103 doesn't have "w" status in ku savings type so we are not updating it to zero.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you want to update the tables permanently or do it on selecting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select s.*,
             sum(case when statustype = 'w' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by accountnumber, yearquarter, savingstype) as num_ws,
             sum(unpaid_bal) over (partition by accountnumber, yearquarter, savingstype) as sum_unpaid_bal
      from savings s
     )
update toupdate
    set unpaid_bal = 0
    where num_ws > 0 and sum_unpaid_bal = 0;
```